# Evaluate $\int\sin(x^2)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

Can you evaluate $$\int\sin(x^2)\mathrm{d}x \quad ?$$

I have tried substituting $p=x^2$ as well as integrating by parts, but then I came across an answer [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080906082251AAphSMb) which says that there is no way of working it out without using a computer.

Comment: It's a non-trivial integral if I remember correctly.

Comment: look for "Fresnel Integral"

Comment: it is this kind of integral $\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} x\right)$

Comment: It would be quite mean if the university asked us this in a test, because there is no solution!

Comment: A computer will not be more nor less successful as there is no closed formula using elementary functions. An educated mathematician will immediately recognize a Fresnel integral. If you mean "requires numerical methods", these can also be carried out by hand.

Answer (score 4):

Just read the wiki page on Fresnel Integrals:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral